# How to set two classpaths for java in ".bashrc" file?

Tags: java, ubuntu, classpath

I am trying to create rmi program with jdbc but there seems classpath conflict between my sql and rmi whenever i use them simualtaneously. So how can i set two classpaths for java in ".bashrc"?

Answer (score 0):

You want to look into tools like "galternatives" and the underlying "alternatives" system.

Basically you don't do such things manually within your bash rc; you want to use tooling that allows for management of various different "configuration setups".